# manually entered redirects are going missing / deleted

Tags: 7, redirection

My site is using the [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) 7.x-1.0 patched with [no redirect loops](https://www.drupal.org/node/1796596) and I am seeing some odd behavior.  Some 400 redirects have been manually entered into the site, and about a dozen of those are no longer there.  Six have been repeatedly entered and repeatedly gone missing.  There is nothing obvious about those in relation to the other that would make them rejected or targeted for deletion, and a user is not doing this.  I have added a [hook_redirect_delete](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!redirect!redirect.api.php/function/hook_redirect_delete/7) with a backtrace, but this has not happened in 2 the two days I have been watching sofar.

Any ideas?

Small updates:  My site is set to never delete redirects.  Some of the redirects disappear immediately, and some were working for over a year with no problems.  The 400 redirects in question all start with 'search/' because we want to shortcut certain keywords to certain pages.  One example being 'search/wine' => node/9303

Comment: How long are the redirects thee for before they go missing? There is a setting on the redirects settings page to delete redirects that have not been used in a certain period of time.

Comment: I noticed that on one of my sites with the URL that I know I definitely had manually setup to redirect. I have expiration setting that @rooby mentioned set to never delete. I thought I was hallucinating until I saw this question.

Comment: "user is not doing this" - how can you be sure? " this has not happened in 2 the two days I have been watching sofar" - did any disappearance happened in these 2 days?

Comment: I can be sure because I know the 4 people with the permission level to alter redirects, and have asked them.  I am as sure as the permissions are reliable.  No disappearance has happened these two days, as inferred by a mysql query showing the same total in the redirects table.

Comment: Since Drupageddon I'm skeptical about any assumptions like "I know who can log in", unless they are confirmed.

Comment: Okay.  Assuming this is not a [genius malignus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_demon) arbitrarily deleting 3.175% of the search term shortcut redirects... and an unauthorized user would be more categorical in their selections, I can say with reasonable certainty this is not a user.